# why javascript doesn't consider overloaded methods instead of considering one which is having more parameters

Tags: javascript

I've java script functions defined below.

```
function getSum(a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}
function getSum(a, b, c)
{
    return a + b + c ;
}
function getSum(a, b, c, d)
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}


getSum(1,2);
getSum(1,2, 3);
getSum(1,2,3, 4);
getSum(undefined, 1,2);

getSum(undefined, undefined, 1,2);
```

Each time I call getSum() only the latest version ie. one with 4 parameters is getting called?  how this is happened?  this is a bit different from java overloading?

Please explain how javascript handles overloading of methods.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. I don't know what kind of explanation you're looking for.

Comment: You have the [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which is the closest alternative to the overloading

Comment: An `object` can not have many `keys` with same name.... I hope this answers the question..

Comment: You should have a look at the topic Javascript Hoisting @raju

Comment: @Rayon Dabre, yes  same key 'getSum'  is getting updated with the latest function , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each time I call getSum() only the latest version ie. one with 4
>   parameters is getting called? how this is happened? this is a bit
>   different from java overloading?

Because initial definitions of `getSum` were overwritten with later ones and finally last definition will be used whenever the method is invoked.

This has nothing to do with overloading, it is just the case of the **order in which those function definitions** were defined.

If

```
function getSum(a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

was defined last, it would have picked up that for all your function invocations.

Comment: Hi @gurvinder372,  I tested changing the order of these methods, it is working as you've said, last getSum(a, b) is replacing the other functions. Thanks.